# Owin: ExternalLogin clientId & secret based on url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin

I am new to OWIN and want to know if it's possible to change the ClientId & Client secret in our startup class based on the url? We are using OWIN in a multi tenant site and really need a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

The app secret/id are stored in a class which is initialised once at startup and then used by each built-in implementation of `AuthenticateCoreAsync`.

Although there's nothing stopping you changing this value after the app has started up, its definitely not threadsafe to do so (since this is effectively a shared global object)

Unfortunately you can't change this behaviour either since these implementations are all marked internal, and hard-coded to pull the appsecret/id from this options object.

See: https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook/FacebookAuthenticationHandler.cs

```
string tokenRequest = "grant_type=authorization_code" +
    "&code=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(code) +
    "&redirect_uri=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(redirectUri) +
    "&client_id=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(Options.AppId) +
    "&client_secret=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(Options.AppSecret);
```

it seems your only option is to be to take a copy of the code (since it is open source) and modify the behaviour to suit your needs

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean- where would you like to change the ClientID and Client secret? On the third-party provider or locally? Can you clarify a bit please?

This may or may not work - though I see no reason why it should not:

```
if(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl == "YourUrlHere")
            { 

            var fbOptions =  new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AppId = "etcetc",
                AppSecret = "etcetc"
            };
}
else if( etc. etc.)
{
}
```

Comment: Want to change it locally in our startup class

Comment: I do not think your startup class can change once your application has started - as it is responsible for creating the OWIN middleware that handles your authentication, if that is what you're asking - as for using different keys based on URL. I think you could set this up on your configuration file so as for the proper URL to be selected when the App fires up for the first time, but I do not think you can do this dynamically. I could be wrong, but I don't think you can.

Comment: RawUrl is just a '/' (slash) and Request.Url is appearing as http://127.0.0.1/ although site is running on http://localhost:64827/

Comment: There are different extensions to request giving you different urls. Imo yours is a configuration problem more than anything since client secrets are tied to particular urls to begin with prelaunch. You should choose  your values based on your app during app launch phase :)

Comment: I tried both methods app.Run & app.Use but for some reason ConfigureAuth(app) always get called before than anything else.

Comment: Configure Auth will always be called first due to how katana works.any change you wish for you must either make into the startup class or as the friend states below,configure your own code.

Comment: thanks for your time and help. I think I would need to look into the katana source code to get this working.

Comment: No problem, glad to have been of small assistance if any !